# How to create and insert a column with categorical variables for specific ranges

Tags: r, regex, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe with over a thousand rows with very long sample names and therefore wanted to add a categorical index.

For example to this dataframe:

```
sample               ...
Br_LV_0040324_BC1_1  ...
Br_LV_0040324_BC1_2  ...
Br_LV_0040324_BC1_3  ...
Br_LV_0040324_BC1_4  ...
Br_LV_0040324_LBR_1  ...
Br_LV_0040324_LBR_2  ...
```

add a categorical index so it looks like:

```
Index   sample               ...
BC1     Br_LV_0040324_BC1_1  ...
BC1     Br_LV_0040324_BC1_2  ...
BC1     Br_LV_0040324_BC1_3  ...
LBR     Br_LV_0040324_LBR_4  ...
LBR     Br_LV_0040324_LBR_1  ...
LBR     Br_LV_0040324_LBR_2  ...
```

I ended up counting the number of groups by eye and figured I could just create a dataframe with the same amount of levels as my data and then assign labels by range, manually. So I tried

```
s1 <- sample(0:1, 1022, replace = TRUE)
Index <- as.data.frame(s1, labels = "yes")
Index[1:32,1] <- "BC1"
Index[33:88,1] <- "LBR"
...
Index <- Index[,-2]
```

It worked, but I'm sure there has to be some easier way than using this convoluted method and also counting the ranges by eye!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You can use `base::strsplit`.*

Here, I split the `sample` column at each `_`. The fourth element of separated character list is our index. I am using `[4]` within `lapply` to get the 4th element of each row.

```r
s1$Index <- lapply(strsplit(s1$sample, split = "_"), `[`, 4)

# >                sample Index
# > 1 Br_LV_0040324_BC1_1   BC1
# > 2 Br_LV_0040324_BC1_2   BC1
# > 3 Br_LV_0040324_BC1_3   BC1
# > 4 Br_LV_0040324_BC1_4   BC1
# > 5 Br_LV_0040324_LBR_1   LBR
# > 6 Br_LV_0040324_LBR_2   LBR
```

*We can also use `regex`:*

```r
s1$Index <- sub("(?:[^\\_]*\\_){3}([^_]*)([^.*]*)$", "\\1", s1$sample)
```

See the [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/z3N4VM/1/).

***Data:***

```
s1 <- read.table(text="sample
Br_LV_0040324_BC1_1
Br_LV_0040324_BC1_2
Br_LV_0040324_BC1_3
Br_LV_0040324_BC1_4
Br_LV_0040324_LBR_1
Br_LV_0040324_LBR_2", header = T, stringsAsFactor=F)
```

Comment: Or another option is `sub("^([^_]+_){3}([^_]+)_.*", "\\2", s1$sample)` or `stringr::word(s1$sample, 4, sep="_")`

Comment: @akrun I have a question. Can we use a non-capturing group here like `^(?:[^_]+_){3}` as well?

Comment: @jazzurro  Looks like M-- included a similar code in the post

Comment: @akrun Yeah I think he added the non-capturing idea after my comment. Thanks M--.

Comment: @jazzurro Actually it was there before. Anyhow, you're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple ways with *unglue*, borrowing @M-- 's data :

```r
library(unglue)
transform(s1, index = unglue_vec(sample, "{a}_{b}_{c}_{d}_{e}","d"))
#>                sample index
#> 1 Br_LV_0040324_BC1_1   BC1
#> 2 Br_LV_0040324_BC1_2   BC1
#> 3 Br_LV_0040324_BC1_3   BC1
#> 4 Br_LV_0040324_BC1_4   BC1
#> 5 Br_LV_0040324_LBR_1   LBR
#> 6 Br_LV_0040324_LBR_2   LBR

unglue_unnest(s1, sample, "{=.*?}_{=.*?}_{=.*?}_{index}_{=.*?}", remove = FALSE)
#>                sample index
#> 1 Br_LV_0040324_BC1_1   BC1
#> 2 Br_LV_0040324_BC1_2   BC1
#> 3 Br_LV_0040324_BC1_3   BC1
#> 4 Br_LV_0040324_BC1_4   BC1
#> 5 Br_LV_0040324_LBR_1   LBR
#> 6 Br_LV_0040324_LBR_2   LBR
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If all of the `sample` follow the same pattern as shown you can use `sub` to extract the `index`.

```
df$index <- sub(".*_(\\w+)_\\d+", "\\1", df$sample)
df
#               sample index
#1 Br_LV_0040324_BC1_1   BC1
#2 Br_LV_0040324_BC1_2   BC1
#3 Br_LV_0040324_BC1_3   BC1
#4 Br_LV_0040324_BC1_4   BC1
#5 Br_LV_0040324_LBR_1   LBR
#6 Br_LV_0040324_LBR_2   LBR
```